# How do I remove the Office-like button, but keep the ribbon?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, windows-7, mfc

How do I remove the Office-like button, but keep the ribbon?
[image: Visual C++ application with ribbon]

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/SevenGoodiesHelloRibbon.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your CMainFrame class declare the ribbon button:

```
private:
    CMFCRibbonApplicationButton m_wndRibbonButton;
```

Then in the OnCreate method, set the button visibility and assign it to the ribbon bar:

```
m_wndRibbonButton.SetVisible(FALSE);
m_wndRibbonBar.SetApplicationButton(&m_wndRibbonButton, CSize());
```

This is what you'll get:

[image: Ribbon without application button]

Comment: Thank you! This is what I wanted. Do you also know how to remove the quick access menu?

Comment: You're welcome! You can hide the quick access toolbar by removing all the items through the editor. There doesn't seem to be a way to hide the menu though.

Comment: If QAT is still there after you remove all the items in the editor, you may try call `RemoveAll()` of QAT.